# react-router basename not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, no-match

I create a small react app withs this router:

```
<BrowserRouter basename='/hotel/'>
    <Routes />
</BrowserRouter>
```

and this are the routes:

```
<Switch>
    <Layout path="/:agency" component={Home} />
    <Layout path="/:agency/list" component={List} />
    <Layout path="/:agency/detail/:id" component={Detail} />
    <Route component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```

when I try to hit a route without the basename I get this warning on the console:

﻿

> Warning: You are attempting to use a basename on a page whose URL path
>   does not begin with the basename. Expected path "/4123" to begin with
>   "/hotel"

while I'm expecting to get the nomatch route...is there a way to get the nomatch route instead of see my app?

Answer (score -1):

`basename` limits the router's application only to routes beginning with `/hotel`. What you need is to define the `NoMatch` at the root ("/") level, omitting the `basename`. Something like this:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes />
</BrowserRouter>

...

<Switch>
  <Layout exact path="/hotel/:agency" component={Home} />
  <Layout exact path="/hotel/:agency/list" component={List} />
  <Layout exact path="/hotel/:agency/detail/:id" component={Detail} />
  <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```